# MS Access: Search for record with combo box in Web Database

Tags: ms-access-2010

I'm not really used to Web Databases and only slightly more used to Access overall! I'm using Access 2010 and I have set up a web database. I have now added a Combo Box to a form which gives me a dropdown with my contact names and allows me to type a contact name that shows up in the box. When I have done this on a regular (non web) database, I have been able to set it up using the 'Wizard', and after selecting the 'Find a record on my form based on the value...' option, clicking the result in the box, or dropdown, brought me to that record, however, this isn't happening with my web database. Denied the help of the 'Wizard' I have had to try and set it up manually. I have set the Row Source to 'contact name', so the data is showing, it just doesn't go to the relevant record when I click on a name. I checked the embedded macro for the non-web database combo box, hoping I could figure it and apply it to the web one, however , this uses 'searchForRecord', which isn't on the web macro dropdown options.

Is there a relatively easy way to set a search box that will allow me to type a name, or part of a name, present a drop down of matching results and go to that record at the click of a chosen name, on a WEB database?

Thanks for reading,

Peter.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the SetFilter macro, this will filter out everything except the matches. 
Add a new Action

```
SetFilter
Where Condition  [Field_name_you_are_searching] Like "*" & [combo_box_name] & "*"
```

you can leave the Control Name blank.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm getting an 'error in my expression, or attempted to use an undeclared parameter'. Also, this brings up a query parameter box. I'm looking to simply type in a box, the dropdown filters down to my results, then, when I click on a result, it goes to that record, much like the third option the 'Wizard' sets up on a regular database for combo boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Very Late answer, but you never know who will search for something like this!

I have been working on this [Embedded Macro] for three days, to no avail but after reading this post, a final success:

As kenf correctly suggested:

```
Set Filter
```

Although, my where condition was slightly different (as I was getting the exact same undeclared parameters pop-up message box ).  Instead, I used:

```
[WORK_EFFORT] Like "*" & [Forms]![Team Work Efforts]![Combo967] & "*"
```

Where I spelled out the form, and the field I was trying to update (form first then field).  `WORK_EFFORT` is the field name of the project. Well you know what the auto ID is, and Team Work Efforts is the name of the form , which is the HTML front end on SharePoint 2013, and combo967, is the drop down, users will use to pick the project they want to update.

Works perfectly.

I have about 20 records, and I can search through the name from a drop down combo box.  HOWEVER:

One thing I had to first, was use the query builder; then select the ID and project name fields.  Of course I "hid" the ID field, so I was only searching text names.

Also note the control source is blank, and the row/source is table/query.